# How to get cmake --build to stop on error

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm running `cmake --build`, but when there are errors, it keeps going for quite a while.  I'd prefer if it would stop at the first error.  Is there a way to do that with the cmake build option?

Here is my command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ../
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Comment: Normally, a project's building process stops on the first error. Probably, you need to be more specific about the case when you observe the opposite.

Comment: Well, so you are using Visual Studio 15. But what about the **exact case** when you observe strange behavior? BTW, since it is Visual Studio who actually builds the project (`cmake --build` is just a *wrapper* around the building process), it deserves the tag more than CMake.

Comment: This is a long-standing complaint about Visual Studio's behavior - for example, see the thread starting at https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-April/069321.html .  (In our case, it especially tends to make support complicated, when customers unaware of this behavior report the errors that just say something being linked into the final executable wasn't found, and then we have to ask them to go back to find and report the *first* error(s).)

Answer (score 1):

I can answer for `make` only, but do not know whether it fits for Visual Studio 17 also.

The `make` command supports parallel builds. Every build process runs as far as possible. Either to the end, to next dependency or error.

To stop the workflow at first error just run only on process.

- Errors are easier to find
- Increases time to wait in most of the cases

See `cmake --build` options for more details (at least the `-j` option): [cmake - Build a Project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake.1.html)

Comment: This is one advantage of using the Ninja generator (at least on Linux) - because it doesn't have the recursively defined make targets that run more or less independently, after an error occurs it can stop more quickly and you only have to wait for currently running processes.  (Plus, Ninja temporarily stores output of each process to avoid the interleaving of output from different processes.)